# How to specify `dispatcherTypes` in Spring 3?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

How to specify `dispatcherTypes` in Spring 3?

I am trying to convert an old JSP-Servlet based application to Spring 3 based application. While converting I came across this filter which I converted to an interceptor but I am not sure how to specify `dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD}` in Spring 3.

Please guide.

**EventBuilder.java**

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "EventBuilder", urlPatterns = {"*.jsp"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD})
public class EventBuilder implements Filter {
....
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="*.jsp" />
        <bean class="com.istore.web.filters.EventBuilder"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Interceptors don't do the same thing as filters. There is no concept of `dispatcherTypes` for interceptors.

Comment: Hmmm interesting! I anyhow solved the issue that I was having using `mvc:exclude-mapping` property.